# HTML5 mobile web app camera access

Tags: html

I am developing web application for mobiles for iOS and Android. As per requirements, I need to access mobile camera and take photos (more than one).

Then the photos should be stored in localStorage and then uploaded when user clicks on upload.

I am developing a web apps. It is not native app. I dont want to use phonegap or similar to phonegap.

It should be like normal button. not like choose file button.

Comment: Where is your question? You've just explained what you want to do.

Comment: I want to know how to do @MMM

Comment: Then ask a proper question Sridhar; not only it is rude to just say "I want to do this" without even asking what you need help with, it's also against the rules on this website. _"Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"_ Have a look at the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Otherwise nobody will help you. People here are not suppose to do your work for you.

Answer (score 1):

have a read: [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/) but it will not be supported on all devices.